# Query within a Query - mySQL & php

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to php and mysql as I have been trying to teach myself.   I am used to Classic ASP and am adjusting to php but I am struggling with doing a Query within a Query.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sel_query="Select * from accounts ORDER BY name asc;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $refname = intval($row["referrer"]);

    $sql = "Select name from accounts where userid = '$refname' LIMIT 1";
    $username = mysqli_query($con,$sql)
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);

        echo $row2;
}
```

I am trying to perform a query of the entire table and then as I go though each row, I query the same table again to pull a name based on a referrer column.

How do I properly do this in php/mysql?  Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just do one query with a join? A table can be joined to itself

Comment: To be clear, is this code not working for you? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: I didn't realize a join to itself.   I am not getting the $row2 to show anything and the initial query ends at the first hit on the 2nd query.

Thank you for the Warning... Great info

Comment: Do you really need the additional query / queries within the `while` loop? You're already getting everything from your `accounts` table, so you can simply do `echo $row['name']`.

Comment: I am using the initial query to display the entire table. The 2nd query is to find a name based on what is in the referrer column and then display the name later in the code instead of the string in referrer.

Comment: Is this a typo? `mysql_fetch_assoc` -- that function doesn't exist (anymore). You're using the `mysqli` library so this should be `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Sounds like you don't have php error reporting enabled

Comment: "Sounds like you don't have php error reporting enabled " - I didn't even realize this. OMG, such a difference to be able to see what is wrong!   Thank you everyone as I was able to read and figure it out.  Many many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `;` at the end of your `$username = mysqli_query($con,$sql)` line.

Corrected Version:
`$username = mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Comment: My bad.   I forgot to copy it over.  I do have that in the source and no error.  

I am just not getting any results from the first query until I remark the following line:

//$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);

but then the 2nd query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysql_fetch_assoc` was the problem.   I didn't realize it was there and now have php error reporting turned on and that helps greatly.